# Difference between Specialized String collection and Generic list C#

Tags: c#, generics, stringcollection

What is the difference between a `Specialized String Collection` and a `Generic String List` in C#?

And how to convert a `Specialized` one into a `Generic` one?

```
System.Collections.Specialized.StringCollection specialized = new System.Collections.Specialized.StringCollection() { "s123", "s321" };

System.Collections.Generic.List<string> generic = new System.Collections.Generic.List<string>() { "g123", "g321" };
```

Comment: StringCollection was added before generics were introduced. Use `List<string>`.

Comment: @AnasAlweish my question also ask what is the difference between the two.

Comment: There are many, does it matter? You should be using `List<T>`, does it matter what StringCollection would do or how it does it? For one difference, `List<T>` implements `IEnumerable<T>`, whereas `StringCollection` only implements `IEnumerable` (the non-generic one).

Comment: The core point of the two aren't different though. Both implement a dynamic list of strings you can add strings to.

Comment: As to your second question, `specialized.Cast<string>().ToList()` will do. There is no real use case for `StringCollection` in new code; don't use it unless you have to interoperate with older code.

Comment: @JeroenMostert this is why I asked, because I working on some old code where methods uses `StringCollection` instead of `List<string>`. So I was wondering why they use `StringCollection`

Comment: Note that if you *are* interoperating with older code, using `StringCollection` where asked for is still a better idea than continuously converting back and forth between `StringCollection` and `List<string>` -- that just eats memory and cycles. You can use `.Cast<string>()` if you need type-safe enumeration on an incidental basis.

Comment: If you want to see the exact differences, take a look at the reference source for [List<T>](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/collections/generic/list.cs) (btw. it is somewhat telling that this doesn't even list the `System.Collections.Specialized` namespace) and [StringCollection](https://github.com/microsoft/referencesource/blob/master/System/compmod/system/collections/specialized/stringcollection.cs).

Comment: take a look at this [to know diff](http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?640282-System-Collections-Specialized-StringCollection-vs-System-Collections-Generic-List(Of)